# Best way to count all elements in a cell array?

Tags: matlab, cell

I want to count all elements in a cell array, including those in "nested" cells.

For a cell array

```
>> C = {{{1,2},{3,4,5}},{{{6},{7},{8}},{9}},10}

C = {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}    [10]
```

The answer should be `10`.

One way is to use `[C{:}]` repeatedly until there are no cells left and then use `numel` but there must be a better way?

Comment: look at the source code for functions like CELLDISP and CELLPLOT. The answer is **recursion**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are only interested in the *number of elements*, here is a simplified version of [flatten.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27009-flatten-nested-cell-arrays/content/flatten.m) that [@Ansari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11308652/97160) linked to:

```
function n = my_numel(A)
    n = 0;
    for i=1:numel(A)
        if iscell(A{i})
            n = n + my_numel(A{i});
        else
            n = n + numel(A{i});
        end
    end
end
```

The result:

```
>> C = {{{1,2},{3,4,5}},{{{6},{7},{8}},{9}},10};
>> my_numel(C)
ans =
    10
```

---

### EDIT:

If you are feeling lazy, we can let [CELLPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellplot.html) do the counting:

```
hFig = figure('Visible','off');
num = numel( findobj(cellplot(C),'type','text') );
close(hFig)
```

Basically we create an invisible figure, plot the cell array, count how many "text" objects were created, then delete the invisible figure.

This is how the plot looks like underneath:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: ok the CELLPLOT thing is not always reliable, that was just for fun :)

Comment: +1 just for the cellplot.  Didn't know about that until now =P

Answer (score 2):

Put this in a function (say `flatten.m`) (code from [MATLAB Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27009-flatten-nested-cell-arrays/content/flatten.m)):

```
function C = flatten(A)
C = {};
for i=1:numel(A)  
    if(~iscell(A{i}))
        C = [C,A{i}];
    else
       Ctemp = flatten(A{i});
       C = [C,Ctemp{:}];
    end
end
```

Then do `numel(flatten(C))` to find the total number of elements.

If you don't like making a separate function, you can employ this clever (but nasty) piece of code for defining a flatten function using anonymous functions (code from [here](http://apageofinsanity.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/functional-implementation-of-flatten/)):

```
flatten = @(nested) feval(Y(@(flat) @(v) foldr(@(x, y) ifthenelse(iscell(x) | iscell(y), @() [flat(x), flat(y)], @() {x, y}), [], v)), nested);
```

Either way, you need to recurse to flatten the cell array then count.